# Python: using database instance across submodules

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I'm writing a Flask app and I instantiate a mongo database in main.py.

I've got a submodule called `user.py` that holds class `User`. `main.py` takes login credentials and sends it to the class User which handles the rest.

How can I cleanly pass my mongo instance to the User class? I've tried static variables in a `config.py` file but they don't work because the variables are always None when `user.py` tries to use them.

Right now I'm resorting to passing in mongo as a parameter, but this seems like a dirty way to do it considering there will be many modules. Here's my code;

```
# Setup app and database
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://'
mongo = PyMongo(app)
```

Comment: Why not just import `mongo` directly into your `user.py` file?

Comment: @gtalarico because I already import user.py directly in main, so when I import mongo directly in user.py, it results in circular imports and i get "cannot import name 'User'

Comment: Hi @tash. I have added a full response below.
This is quite common in flask and the solution is to move the line importing user into main to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can import `mongo` directly into your `user.py` module.

To avoid circular import error, you just have to move the imports to the bottom of the file. As long as you import User into main after app is defined, it should resolve the circular import:

#### user.py

```
from .main import mongo
# class User():
# ... Your Code
```

#### main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
mongo = PyMongo(app)

from .user import User
```

---

Moving imports to the bottom are normally not a good idea, but in Flask is quite common. Below is an example of a similar scenario from the official flask documentation:

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import app.views


# views.py
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

http://flask-.readthedocs.io/en/0.6/patterns/packages/#simple-packages

> Do the importing at the bottom of the file [...]
>
> Every Python programmer hates them, and yet we just added some: circular imports (That’s when two modules depend on each other. In this case views.py depends on **init**.py). Be advised that this is a bad idea in general but here it is actually fine. The reason for this is that we are not actually using the views in **init**.py and just ensuring the module is imported and we are doing that at the bottom of the file.